# Screen launching in Android

Tags: android

Suppose Screen1 is the main screen of an Android application MyAndroid. Now if another screen, Screen2 has to be opened from Screen1, then which of the following are true?

1. Screen2 has to be a part of MyAndroid.
2. Screen2 can exist in any other Android application installed on the device.
3. Screen2 will always be launched asynchronously.
4. Screen2 can be launched synchronously.
5. Screen2 can return a result code to Screen1 if launched with startActivity.
6. Screen2 can return a result code to Screen1 if launched with startSubActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen2 **can** be a part of MyAndroid.
Screen2 can exist in any other Android application installed on the device - only if that screen can be launched with intent that you can fire.
Screen2 can return a result code to Screen1 if launched with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).
Screen2 can return a result code to Screen1 if launched with startSubActivity - same as startActivityForResult.

Answer (score 0):

1. Screen2 can be a part of MyAndroid.
2. Screen2 can exist in any other Android application installed on the device - only if that screen can be launched with    intent that you can fire.
3. Screen2 will always be Launched Asynchronously.
4. Screen2 can return a result code to Screen1 if launched with
   startActivityForResult.